# Computing the condition to solve a set membership problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck with the following problem for the last few weeks

Alex , Bob and Charlie stand for local election.
Given fractions
a - fraction of voters prefer Alex to Bob
b - fraction of voters prefer Bob to Charlie
c - fraction of voters prefer Charlie to Alex
Which of the following cannot be values of (a,b,c)
a. (0.51 ,0.51, 0.51)
b. (0.68 ,0.68, 0.68)
c. (0.49 ,0.49, 0.49)

I reasoned (initially) that using formal notions of set theory -
$a = A\cap\bar B$
$b = B\cap\bar C$
$c = C\cap\bar A$  where
      A  = fraction of voters that will vote Alex
      B  = ..............do...................Bob
      C  = ................do..................Charlie

Then undertook some tedious/clumsy usage of venn diagrams to formulate some condition that may strike the odd one out.I am clueless after many tries.
Any idea/hints will be helpful.
For your information, I think my intial assumptions given above wont work.
And, the answer to this question was given as option **(b)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v=v_{ABC}+v_{ACB}+v_{BAC}+v_{BCA}+v_{CAB}+v_{CBA}$ where for instance
$v_{ABC}$ stands for the number of voters that have Alex on top,
Bob on second and Charlie on third position.

Then we have fractions $f_{AB}=\frac{v_{ABC}+v_{ACB}+v_{CAB}}{v}$,
$f_{BC}=\frac{v_{ABC}+v_{BAC}+v_{BCA}}{v}$ and $f_{CA}=\frac{v_{BCA}+v_{CAB}+v_{CBA}}{v}$
This leads to $f_{AB}+f_{BC}+f_{CA}=\frac{v_{ABC}+v_{BCA}+v_{CAB}+v}{v}\leq\frac{2v}{v}=2$
so option b (that is: $f_{AB}=f_{BC}=f_{CA}=0.68$) cannot be true.

Comment: -Thanks a lot! I wonder why it didnt occur to me before.